# Не выводится картинка на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

Натягиваю сайт на вордпресс и есть страница с портфолио, там выведены посты где при наведении на картинку вылазит иконка глаза и при нажатии должна открыться картинка побольше размером на той же самой страннице. Вот скрин как должно выводить картинку: https://ibb.co/17MHn3B

В исходном коде указана ссылка и в ней путь к картинке.

```
<a href="img/portfolio-3.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Я пробовал ставить туда `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` но не выводится
Подскажите как можно ее вывести

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном вами коде как минимум используется относительная загрузка изображения.

```
<a href="img/portfolio-3.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Если ваш текущий адрес страницы mysite.ru/page/one, то ссылка будет восприниматься как mysite.ru/page/one/img/portfolio-3.jpg

Чтобы этого избежать, добавьте слеш ("/") в начале имени изображения.

```
<a href="/img/portfolio-3.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

При этом, это изображение должно существовать по адресу вашего сайта, например, mysite.ru/img/portfolio-3.jpg